# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple Controller with a function.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DockerController {

  @Autowired
private DockerService dockerService;

  @PostMapping("/docker/container/{containerName}/pause")
public boolean pauseContainer(@PathVariable String containerName) {
    dockerService.pauseContainer(containerName);
    return true;
}

}
```

But when i try to run it from the angular app i get

> zone.js:2969 POST
>   http://localhost:8080/api/docker/container/Env666/pause 403 ()
>   http://localhost:8080/api/docker/container/Env666/pause: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

This started happening after I used the service functionallity.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166984/delete-method-cors-issue-in-rest-controller/43167508#43167508
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully reproduce the CORS error, contrary to [Spring CrossOrigin Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html#methods--) telling that :

> By default the supported methods are the same as the ones to which a controller method is mapped.

I had to specify the method manually in the CrossOrigin annotation :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders="*", methods={RequestMethod.POST})
```